# Absolute value in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I have this inside my function and i want to get its absolute value .

```
return (int(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty)))%100000);
```

Comment: How about `negativeValue >= 0 ? negativeValue : -negativeValue`?

Comment: Furthermore, assuming that always `negativeValue < 0` (why would you call it that way otherwise?), how about `-negativeValue`?

Comment: BTW, no offense, but the question looks really low-quality. And on top of that, `abs.(x)` isn't even a valid syntax in any other language.

Comment: Yeah i know but Stack told me to put some code haha ! @goodvibration.

Comment: The first answer is very good i'll use it but i wanted some pre-defined method ^^

Comment: That's not a problem to put code, but why not by the least make it look like code? For example, since when does a predefined method (or any method for that matter) is succeeded by `.` when called? Also, why use the variable name `negativeValue` for a value which is obviously not always negative?

Comment: Yes you're right  i'll copy paste my code, i think i was in hurry to get an answer. thank u :D

Comment: Why on earth are you interested in converting the result of `keccak256` into a (signed) `int`??? I have a feeling that `uint256` (or its alias - `uint`) suffice here, unless for some odd reason you want the actual signed (2s-complement) representation of the result of `keccak256`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the absolute value of `int(keccak256(...))`, you can implement an auxiliary function in your contract:

```
function abs(int x) private pure returns (int) {
    return x >= 0 ? x : -x;
}
```

And then use `abs(int(keccak256(...)))`.

However, I do not quite see why you (or anyone else for that matter) would be interested in converting the result of `keccak256` into a signed integer.

So unless for some odd reason you really want the actual 2s-complement representation of the result of `keccak256`, using `uint256` (or its alias - `uint`) instead of `int` in your code should be sufficient for your requirements.

Note that unless the result of `keccak256` is 0, it won't get the absolute value of that result. But it will always give you a non-negative integer which represents that result with no information-loss.

Comment: So as you told me before im testing if the value is negative or not, and if its the case i multiplying it by -1, i can not use abs(int(keccak256(...))) i get an error saying that abs does not exist.
And to answer your question this is for generating a positive random number.

Comment: @CHARFEDDINEAmine: You've implemented `abs` as I wrote above and you cannot use `abs(int(keccak256(...)))`??? Why, what error do you get? And if a positive number is all you're interested in, then as I explained at the bottom of the answer, you may as well just replace `int` with `uint`.

Comment: Nevermind, i didn't know you were talking about the function you just made. 
That's what i did exactelly after u commented the answer, Thanks again !

Comment: Yes uint256 replies to my needs, to be honest i didn't know the difference until you mentioned it.