# How absolute value work in solidity?

Tags: solidity, integers

For some reason, I will get two values which are uint256.

How do I calculate uint256 then get the absolute value?

```
uint256 a = 5;
uint256 b = 9;

return a-b; // will be return 4
return b-a; // will be return 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, `uint` is *unsigned*. This means it can only be positive. If you're trying your example code in Solidity version 0.8.x, `a - b` will give you an exception since it would go negative.

To accomplish what you want, you could use the following function (taken from https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84391/31933):

```
function abs(int x) private pure returns (int) {
    return x >= 0 ? x : -x;
}
```

Note that the function uses `int` type (which can have negative values) instead of `uint`.

Comment: Thanks, I just converted uint to int, then put integer to this function, it works!